# changing div order on small screens only

Tags: css, html

i have a problem with order div on small screen.
My code:

```
<header>
    <nav>...</nav>
</header>

<div id="main">
    <section id="slider">...<section>
    <section id="new_articles">
        <article>...</article>
        <article>...</article>
        <article>...</article>
        <article>...</article>
    <section>
</div>

<aside>
    <section id="calendar">...<section>
    <section id="ads">...<section>
    <section id="forum">...<section>
</aside>

<footer>...</footer>
```

[image: my layout]

I would like to show this in the order:
1. header
2. slider
3. calendar
4. ads
5. new articles
6. forum
7. footer

what i should change?
"slider", "new articles" and "forum" have a dynamic height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [order](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp). Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can play with float:

Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/3f1s70er/1/

When some element is 2nd in the flow, but has `float: left` and element that is 1st in the flow, but has `float: right` - then those elements have different order.

Comment: I did something like that https://jsfiddle.net/3f1s70er/2/ i cann't do that because some div have dynamic height

Answer (score -1):

You can use media queries To make It responsive

Refer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Too vague to be useful.